# Proof of Corollary 2.4 in Stein and Shakarachi Fourier Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, absolute-value

The book states that: $$2\pi \hat{f}(n) = \frac{-1}{n^{2}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} {f^{\prime \prime}(\theta) e^{-in\theta} d\theta}$$

Therefore, $$2\pi |n|^{2} |\hat{f}(n)| \leq \left| \int_{0}^{2\pi} {f^{\prime \prime}(\theta) e^{-in\theta} d\theta}\right|$$

I do not know how, could anyone explain to me please?

thanks.

Comment: Looks like that is self evident, you don't mean how to prove if the absolute value to be inside the integration?

Comment: No I mean if the absolute value outside the integration ..... why  is it self evident?

Comment: it follows directly from multiplying both sides by $-n^2$ and taking absolute value.

Comment: yeah .... sorry

Comment: And, actually, the inequality is an equality.

Comment: @TrialAndError but the book wrote it inequality ..... is it popular in mathematics as $\leq$ means less than or equal so the equality is one of the propabilities?

Comment: It's technically correct, but it's sloppy and confusing to write $\le$ when you clearly have $=$.